# How to get filtered array with defineProperty JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, defineproperty

I've tried looking for a way of doing it but found none.

I want to filter out array items when I'm accessing the array. For example: filter out only negative values

```js
let arr = [-1, -2, -4, -5, 8, 9, 10, -7, 5, 7, 8, 4, -12];
let o = {
  arr: arr
};

Object.defineProperty(o, 'arr', {
  get: () => { /* filter only negative values */ }
});

// should print only positive values
console.log(o.arr)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter

```js
let arr = [-1, -2, -4, -5, 8, 9, 10, -7, 5, 7, 8, 4, -12];
let o = {
  array: arr
};

Object.defineProperty(o, 'arr', {
  get: () => {
    return o.array.filter(a => a >= 0)
  }
});

console.log(o.arr)
```

Comment: And what if I dont have pointer to the array?

Comment: Im not sure how you could not have a pointer to it. Please explain more

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and this(context)

```js
let arr = [-1, -2, -4, -5, 8, 9, 10, -7, 5, 7, 8, 4, -12];
let o = {
  arr,
};

Object.defineProperty(o, 'negative', {
  // return array values where item < 0
  get: function () {return this.arr.filter(item => item < 0)}
});

// should print only positive values
console.log(o.negative)
```